# Typing hinting the return type of a fn returning a subclass

Tags: python

I have a function that takes a class a parameter and returns a (constructed) subclass; essentially a class-decorator. In the most minimal example

```py
# Some baseclass that may come from the current module/stdlib/wherever
class FooBase:
    pass

# A user-defined subclass
class FooDerived(FooBase):
    pass

# foo() takes any `FooBase`-type, including its subclasses
def foo(baseclass: FooBase) -> ?:
    class Inner(baseclass):
        pass
    return Inner

# NewFoo is a class that has to be a subclass of `FooBase`, derived from `FooDerived`
NewFoo = foo(FooDerived)
```

Here, `Inner` is a subtype of whatever `baseclass` is. Is there a way to type-hint this relationship - the function will return a type (not a value of a type!) that is a subtype of what `baseclass` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Type`:

```py
from typing import Type

class FooBase:
    pass

class FooDerived(FooBase):
    pass

def foo(baseclass: Type[FooBase]) -> Type[FooBase]:
    class Inner(baseclass):
        pass
    return Inner
```

Comment: if `baseclass` is of `typing.Type[T]`, it is not valid as a type in `class Inner(baseclass)` according to mypy